# Ubuntu 18.04 reporting system issues, crashing

Tags: crash

I am using the most recent edition of Ubuntu 18.04 as far as my linux noob head can tell, the problem I've been having is quite odd:

About a minute after I turn my system on, an error message will show up "A system program problem was detected" prompting me to report it. I do so and go on with my life.

Or, at least I used to. Today, after clicking away the prompt, my system did something weird, it went to a black screen, with a small line of text: [image]

I couldn't type anything, I tried pressing esc, various function keys, but nothing did anything, so I restarted my system.

What is causing this? I don't think I have any weird files installed, but maybe?

Other things I've noticed: Sometimes, my audio doesn't work and i have to reboot to get it to function, and also I can't quite remember what caused this, potentially after clicking away another one of those prompts, I restarted and I got a weird boot menu, with like 4 options, Boot into Ubuntu, or do memtest86 or something.

Answer (score 0):

Well i don't have the solution to this .But,what i know is that the latest version of Ubuntu is 19.10 and the "weird menu" is called Grub menu. 
It shows up every time i start my computer too .
It basically asks how to boot your system.